# How to extract digits only between deliminators?

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract all digits that are found *between* two `-` separators.

Example:

```
test-555-2468-123
```

Desired result to extract:

```
555
2468
```

I tried using regex as follows: `[\d+]+`. This at least gives me all digits in a block. But how can I add restriction that the digit must be pre- and postfixed with a `-` character?

Comment: Use `-(\d+)-` and extract value from first captured group.

Comment: This would only give me `555`. But I need all groups.

Comment: Use `while(matcher.find())` to retrieve all groups

Comment: @JaySmith searches in regex are exhaustive in nature, u cannot reuse the same character twice, that is why u need lookarounds for this case, see anubhava's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use lookarounds in your regex since it involves overlapping matches:

```
(?<=-)\d+(?=-)
```

In Java code:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=-)\\d+(?=-)");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sysfgf/1)

- `(?<=-)` - Positive Lookbehind to assert that previous position has a hyphen
- `(?=-)` - Positive Lookahead to assert that next position has a hyphen

Comment: For look-arounds read this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html otherwise http://www.regular-expressions.info/ has lots of goodies to learn regex

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that uses a little less regex and (I guess) more straightforward.

```
String str = "test-555-2468-123";

// converting the split array into an array list
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Arrays.stream(str.split("\\-")).forEach(list::add);

// ensure that there must be a "-" before and after by removing the first and last element
list.remove(0);
list.remove(list.size() - 1);

// filter the elements that contains only numbers
list.stream().filter(x -> Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(x).matches()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Why should I split beforehand if regex pattern matcher is used anyways?

Comment: I just thought this is a more straightforward solution, using split to ensure that a `=` is present on both sides. I've always found regex to be less readable. @membersound